# What are the required IAM permissions to create an AWS CodeDeploy Application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I'm setting up a new employee with proper rights to work on CodeDeploy.

I've given the AWSCodeDeployFullAccess IAM role to this person, but when they attempt to create a new Application in CodeDeploy, the "Service Role ARN" drop down is NOT populated.  What's missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes across this (and so I can come back here when I need it again), the answer is you need to add IAMReadOnlyAccess to the user that needs to create CodeDeploy Applications.